# Finding the intersection of a family of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For this happy family of sets how can one find the intersection and union.

For each real number r let $A_r=\{|r|,2|r|,|r|+1\}$ and let the family $L=\{A_r:r\in \mathbb{R}  \}.$

So would

$A_{-1}=\{1,2\}$

$A_2=\{2,3,4\}$

$A_{-7}=\{7,14,8\}$

Then the $\bigcup A_r$

I think it will be all real number greater than $0$ because taking absolute value of anything is positive.

But what can intersection be ?

Comment: Did you mean to type $\{\,\,\}$ in the definition of $A_r$?

Comment: No it seems the book I used has the [] for A_r instead of {}

Comment: opp I made an error I meant 2 absolute value (r) very follish of me

Comment: I am sorry, is $A_r$ a set, according to $A_{-1}$ or an interval? I have just edited and I wonder if I have made a mistake.

Comment: No it is edited correctly I am new to this set notation so I initially made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection is the empty set. Note that $A_{-1}\cap A_{-7}=\emptyset.$

With respect to the union you are right. Note that $r\in A_r$ for any $r\in \Bbb{R},r\ge 0.$ Thus $[0,\infty)\subset \bigcup_{r\in \Bbb{R}} A_r.$ On the other hand, any element of $\bigcup_{r\in \Bbb{R}} A_r$ is a nonnegative real number. So $\bigcup_{r\in \Bbb{R}} A_r=[0,\infty).$

Comment: yes that makes sense thanks